# How efficient is Kubernetes Dynamic Volume Provisioning?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, provisioning

[Kubernetes Dynamic Volume Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning) gives a handy way to supply pods with dynamically-allocated storage volumes. For example, [NFS Provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/nfs-provisioner) transparently spins up an NFS server and exposes that storage to client pods with Kubernetes volume interface, on-demand.

But how efficient is that? Does provisioner introduce another network protocol layer to communicate with client pod/container, in addition to NFS client-server communication? Or client pod/container talks directly to NFS server once the persistent volume claim was fulfilled?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) when you consider to allocate [Persistent volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) to the Pods in the cluster there is a requirement to specify `StorageClass` in order to find appropriate provisioner (volume plugin) for the storage provider. `StorageClass` defines all the necessary parameters have to be passed to the storage provider and what `provisioner:` should be selected in Kubernetes API `apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1` for the successful creation of `PersistentVolume` which corresponds to `PersistentVolumeClaim` request. 
Find a list of the provisioners supported internally by Kubernetes [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner).

However, you are not limited only with internal volume plugins which are already included in `provisioner: kubernetes.io` module, but there are a lot of external provisioners which can be used for some specific scenarios, look at  [kubernetes-incubator/external-storage](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage) project.

Comment: Is that correct that Persistent Volumes created by NFS Provisioner do not introduce additional network protocol level/overhead, compared to communicating with NFS server directly?

Comment: `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim` are both internal K8s API resources, therefore they contribute with the main provisioner via `kube-apiserver`.

Comment: So it's correct that `PersistentVolume` talks to `kube-apiserver` not only during mount operation, but also when accessing the data? Uh, that's quite suboptimal..